# Let user XXX read error.log in Apache2 Debian

Tags: php, debian, apache2

I have a VPS with last Debian installed.

I've apache2 and I use this vps to practicing with some friends.

By the way, I'm the only one with root ssh access, they have their own folders and accounts(ftp only), in /var/www/html/xxxxx/

The problem is: while they try new things and learn programming something, they need to see error.log of apache2, but they can't, and I need to check it for them and copy paste the errors.

Is there a way to let them see the error.log?

I tried these

- Link the error.log to their folder (and obviously didn't worked)
- Make a script that would copy the error.log to folders on file change. (But i'm not that skilled, and totally don't understand how to use something like: inotifywait).
- PHP script that copy error.log and paste in a file in the folder (access denied.. and it is the expected behavior!!)

I'm pretty sure there is an easy solution I didn't thought of (like a php code to echo the error 500 content, this solution doesn't involve me directly, but I didn't find how to do)

Sorry for my english and if this question is stupid or already answered, I searched a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache is storing error logs in `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` (usually `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) which is accessible only by root user.

You can specify custom error log location per website in your `vhost` config
 or `.htaccess`.

You should think about displaying errors instead of logging them at development stage.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you just give some hint about "displaying errors" ? Many thanks

Comment: [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is a PHP runtime configuration. It's configured in the `php.ini` file or it can be configured in your `vhost` configuration. [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) can be useful too.